# Swift decodable snake case key which include numbers Issue

Tags: swift, codable, decodable

I have a problem decoding JSON which has keys in the snake case including numbers.
I've already spent days trying to solve it and can't tell I see any solution to it. Even though I need it badly. Nor do I have an idea why it is failing. Any help here is appreciated. Thanks!

for example JSON:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "symbol": "A",
      "v_price_24h": "39652.50",

    }
  ],
  "time_now": "1645931312.379455"
}
```

Will throw error:

```
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "vPrice24h", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "result", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"vPrice24h\", intValue: nil) (\"vPrice24h\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

my model property is `vPrice24h`
key `v_price_24h` is in JSON

This works for everything but fails when I have a number in a key

```
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
```

same stuff with my custom one:
I spent days trying to figure it out and can't solve this issue.
Does anyone know how to deal with it?

Here is playground:

```swift
import Foundation

var json = """
{
  "result": [
    {
      "symbol": "A",
      "v_price_24h": "39652.50",

    }
  ],
  "time_now": "1645931312.379455"
}
"""

struct CustomKey: CodingKey {
    let stringValue: String
    let intValue: Int?

    init(stringValue: String) {
        self.stringValue = stringValue
        intValue = nil
    }

    init(intValue: Int) {
        self.intValue = intValue
        stringValue = String(intValue)
    }
}

struct TopModel: Decodable {
    let timeNow: String
    let result: [InsideModel]
}

struct InsideModel: Decodable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case symbol = "symbol"
        case vPrice24h = "v_price_24h"
    }
    let symbol: String
    let vPrice24h: String
}


let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase


let decoder2 = JSONDecoder()
decoder2.keyDecodingStrategy = .custom { keys in
    let last = keys.last!.stringValue
    let snakePattern :String = "(\\w{0,1})_"
    var key = last.capitalized.replacingOccurrences(of: snakePattern, with: "$1", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)

    if key.count > 1 {
        key = key.prefix(1).lowercased() + key.dropFirst()
    }
    print(key, last)
    return CustomKey(stringValue: key)
}

let decoder3 = JSONDecoder()
decoder3.keyDecodingStrategy = .useDefaultKeys

do {
    _ = try decoder.decode(TopModel.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
} catch let thrownError {
    print("", thrownError)
}


do {
    _ = try decoder2.decode(TopModel.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
} catch let thrownError {
    print("✅", thrownError)
}

do {
    _ = try decoder3.decode(TopModel.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
} catch let thrownError {
    print("", thrownError)
}
```

and result

```
 keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "v_price_24h", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "result", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"v_price_24h\", intValue: nil) (\"v_price_24h\").", underlyingError: nil))
timeNow time_now
result result
symbol symbol
vPrice24H v_price_24h

✅ keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "v_price_24h", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "result", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"v_price_24h\", intValue: nil) (\"v_price_24h\").", underlyingError: nil))

 keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "timeNow", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"timeNow\", intValue: nil) (\"timeNow\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in and your custom snake case strategies both convert `v_price_24h` into `vPrice24H`. So, if you rename the field in your struct with a capital H, you can drop every customization except the strategy, and it will work.

```swift
import Foundation

var json = """
{
  "result": [
    {
      "symbol": "A",
      "v_price_24h": "39652.50",

    }
  ],
  "time_now": "1645931312.379455"
}
"""

struct TopModel: Decodable {
    let timeNow: String
    let result: [InsideModel]
}

struct InsideModel: Decodable {
    let symbol: String
    let vPrice24H: String
}


let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

do {
    let model = try decoder.decode(TopModel.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
    print("✅", model)
} catch let thrownError {
    print("❌", thrownError)
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have a question.
In my case, the key in json is "i18n_key" and property is i18nKey, it can parser success.
But, "test_i18n_key" and property is testI18nKey, it parser failure.
I need modify to testI18NKey can be work.
What's the reason?

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest form with `convertFromSnakeCase`

```
let jsonString = """
{
  "result": [
    {
      "symbol": "A",
      "v_price_24h": "39652.50",

    }
  ],
  "time_now": "1645931312.379455"
}
"""

struct TopModel: Decodable {
    let timeNow: String
    let result: [InsideModel]
}

struct InsideModel: Decodable {
    let symbol: String
    let vPrice24h : String
}

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let result = try decoder.decode(TopModel.self, from: Data(jsonString.utf8))
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

the thrown error reveals the mistake

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "vPrice24h", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "result", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "vPrice24h", intValue: nil) ("vPrice24h"), **with divergent representation vPrice24H**, converted to v_price24h.", underlyingError: nil))

Just declare the affected property with a capital letter after the number

```
let vPrice24H : String
```

If you really need the lowercase `h` apply these CodingKeys

```
struct InsideModel: Decodable {
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case symbol, vPrice24h = "vPrice24H"
    }
    
    let symbol: String
    let vPrice24h : String
}
```